# What tier of powerful reward does the Wrathborne Hunt Lure provide?

Tags: destiny-2

In the Season of the Hunt, the main gear grind is provided through the Lure you acquire as part of the quest. Completed hunts can reward some powerful rewards.

[image: Cryptolith lure]

In the image you can see I have 3 of 4 powerful rewards left for this week.

What tier of powerful reward are these? How much light level can they drop above your current base power level?

Comment: Generally, unless they say a higher tier, it's regular powerful gear.